# Adding space char to each item appending to string - have to erase last item. How to improve

Tags: c++, string, vector

This function, vec2string takes a vector of char's and converts to a hex string representation but with a blank space between each byte value.  Just a formatting requirement in my app.  Can anyone think of a way to remove the need for that.

```
std::string& vec2string(const std::vector<char>& vec, std::string& s) {
   static const char hex_lookup[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   for(std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
      s.append(1, hex_lookup[(*it >> 4) & 0xf]);
      s.append(1, hex_lookup[*it & 0xf]);    
      s.append(1, ' ');
   }
   //remove very last space - I would ideally like to remove this***
   if(!s.empty())
      s.erase(s.size()-1);

   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string& vec2string(const std::vector<char>& vec, std::string& s) {
   static const char hex_lookup[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   if (vec.empty())
      return s;
   s.reserve(s.size() + vec.size() * 3 - 1);
   std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = vec.begin();
   s.append(1, hex_lookup[(*it >> 4) & 0xf]);
   s.append(1, hex_lookup[*it & 0xf]);    
   for(++it; it != vec.end(); ++it) {
      s.append(1, ' ');
      s.append(1, hex_lookup[(*it >> 4) & 0xf]);
      s.append(1, hex_lookup[*it & 0xf]);    
   }
   return s;
}
```

Comment: lots of good suggestions but I like the simplicity of this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check in the loop, before appending the characters, if the string is not empty and then add a space. Like:

```
for (...)
{
    if (!s.empty())
        s += ' ';
    ...
}
```

Comment: If it were true, @AndreyI, then the empty check in the original code wouldn't be valid, either.

Comment: Trouble with that, is it checks on every iteration.  Probably not much overhead but it is there.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, Based on the question this is a bug in the original function code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by separating the hex conversion into its own little function:

```
std::string to_hex(char in) { 
    static const char hex_lookup[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::string s;
    s.push_back(hex_lookup[(in>>4) & 0xf];
    s.push_back(hex_lookup[in & 0xf];
    return s;
}
```

Then I'd use `std::transform` to apply that to the whole vector, with my [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489) and a `std::stringstream` to put the pieces together.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "infix_iterator"

std::string vec2string(const std::vector<char>& vec) {
    std::stringstream s;

    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                   infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(s, " "), 
                   to_hex);
    return s.str();
}
```

Also note that rather than modifying an existing string, this creates and returns a new string. At least in my opinion, modifying an existing string is a poor idea -- simply producing a string is much cleaner and more modular. If the caller wants to combine the results into a longer string, that's fine, but it's better for the lower-level function to just do one thing cleanly, and let the higher level function decide what to do with the result.

Comment: I like this approach but is it not a problem returning a local object - the string s?

Comment: Yes, return `string` rather than `string&`

Comment: @user619818: oops - yes. I copied and pasted (then edited) his function signature, but missed editing that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Boost, use algorithm/string/join.hpp.  Otherwise, you could try the Duff's Device approach:

```
string hex_str(const vector<char>& bytes)
{
    string result;
    if (!bytes.empty())
    {
        const char hex_lookup[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        vector<char>::const_iterator it = bytes.begin();
        goto skip;
        do {
            result += ' ';
        skip:
            result += hex_lookup[(*it >> 4) & 0xf];
            result += hex_lookup[*it & 0xf];
        } while (++it != bytes.end());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: isn't returning a local variable a problem?

Comment: No, it's returned by value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::trim`  [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3183616)

```
boost::trim(your_string);
```